# cocos2d - CCSprite not aligned with b2Body

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, ccsprite, levelhelper

If I create a sprite and body with the first batch of code, the sprite is centered on top of the circular body.  But if I create the sprite with the second batch of code, the bottom of the circular body is attached to the top of the sprite.  Both batches of code use the following

**Update 1 -** I changed createBody so that it now takes position as an input.  Then I think I send the correct position in each cause, but I still see the top of the sprite connected to the bottom of the body in the second batch of code.

createBody method:

```
- (void)createBody : (NSNumber *)xPos  yPos:(NSNumber *)yPos {

float radius = 16.0f;

b2BodyDef bd;
bd.type = b2_dynamicBody;
bd.linearDamping = 0.1f;
bd.fixedRotation = true;
bd.position.Set([xPos doubleValue]/PTM_RATIO, [yPos doubleValue]/PTM_RATIO);

body = _world->CreateBody(&bd);

b2CircleShape shape;
shape.m_radius = radius/PTM_RATIO;

b2FixtureDef fd;
fd.shape = &shape;
fd.density = 1.0f;
fd.restitution = 0.0f;
fd.friction = 0.2; 

body->CreateFixture(&fd);
```

}

**First batch of code -**

Hero.mm -

```
- (id)initWithWorld:(b2World *)world {
    if ((self = [super initWithSpriteFrameName:@"animal.png"])) {
      NSNumber *xPos = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.position.x];
      NSNumber *yPos = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.position.y];
      [self createBody:xPos yPos:yPos];
    }
}
```

HellowWorld.mm

```
  _hero = [[[Hero alloc] initWithWorld:_world] autorelease];
    [_terrain.batchNode addChild:_hero];
```

**Second batch of code -**

Hero.mm -

```
 CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"animal.png"];
 [self addChild:sprite];
 NSNumber *xPos = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: sprite.position.x];
 NSNumber *yPos = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: sprite.position.y];
 [self createBody:xPos yPos:yPos];
```

The main difference between the two batches of code is that the first uses **initWithSpriteFrameName** and the second uses **spriteWithSpriteFrameName**. Does anyone know how to center the sprite on the body using spriteWithSpriteFrameName?

The strange thing is that this line in the createBody method

```
     bd.position.Set([xPos doubleValue]/PTM_RATIO, [yPos doubleValue]/PTM_RATIO);
```

doesn't seem to position the body on the sprite, but to position body and sprite in the world coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference that I notice is as follows.

In your first case you initialize your hero as a sprite and call `createBody` which in turn uses `self.position`, ie. the position of the sprite itself.

In your second case, you add a sprite as a child - `createBody` now uses the position of the parent object and not the sprite that you are adding.